# Where can I find an Arca Swiss compatible quick release plate with a lever?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, tripod, quick-release

I am looking for a quick release plate to add to my existing tripod head, which is Arca Swiss compatible and has a lever.

It's important to me that the camera  locks the once inserted. Tightening the lever then prevents the cam from further moving.

I am having a really hard time finding such a plate online. Most quality plates are only offered on a full head. Can you provide me with some advice?

Comment: You're not looking for the A-S system then. There is no "locks in place" aspect to the system. Which, IMO, is a good thing because it makes the system faster and easier to use.

Comment: Are you looking for an Arca-Swiss style clamp that works in a similar way to the Manfrotto RC2 clamp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Really Right Stuff has been suggested; German company Novoflex also makes A-S compatible stuff. A bit more "agricultural" in appearance than the very sleek RRS products, it must be said. Other players are Kirk and Wimberley as well as Arca-Swiss themselves.

Mixing and matching across brands may not be a good idea though; I have some Novoflex lens plates that slide right through my tripod's RRS Quick-release mount... the manufacturing tolerances are just that tiny little bit off.

Comment: From the looks of the plate the camera is fixed once the clamp is tightend. I would prefer a solution were the camera clicks into place, then is tightened further via the clamp.

Comment: Uhh... that's not how the A-S system works.

Comment: Dan W is right, Thom. Arca-Swiss _is_ the industry standard, as good as it gets; it can hold severely heavy camera kit totally safely and rock steady. But it does not click into place like LEGO. The quick-release clamp is, well, quick... it does not take any significant time to mount and dismount the camera, although it is definitely a two-hand job. A screw-release is slower, but possibly more secure.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you're looking for, a [QR clamp base](http://reallyrightstuff.com/Items.aspx?code=ClampsLR&key=cat):

Comment: From the looks of the plate the camera is fixed once the clamp is tightend. I would prefer a solution were the camera clicks into place, then is tightened further via the clamp.

Answer (score 0):

The only Arca Swiss compatible solution that does not require a special plate I know is the head of the upcoming [Peak Design travel tripod](https://www.peakdesign.com/products/travel-tripod). However that head will certainly be available with the whole tripod only.